# How to add views in Android through java and give separate ids

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, button

I am working on an application in which the user is allowed to make certain edited versions of a running piece of music (a "Taal") repeatedly.  My problem is that I want to be able to create a new RelativeLayout with textViews and Buttons when the user create a new "Taal".  For this, I would need to create a new RelativeLayout and Buttons through the Java side of the code rather than the xml, but I do not know how exactly I would be able to assign separate ids for each button when it is created, because Java requires an id in the form R.id.*

Example XML code:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TaalName"
            android:textSize="28dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In this code, I have the Relative layout that would be repeated for each "Taal" that the user creates.  The main thing is that I would require separate ids for the ImageButtons so that clicking one would not delete all of the "Taals" at once

Here is the Java code I am currently using for some of the initialization of the Buttons, note that the delete "Taal" and the relative layout are there now, but in the actual code, they would be generated depending on how many "Taals" the user created"

```
    deleteTaal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    newTaal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

How would I create these buttons and Relative layouts depending on need and how many "Taals" the user decides to create??

Note: I am still learning some of the XML and I don't know how to create Custom Views so if those are necessary, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: any time that you are thinking about creating multiple instances of the same group of Views over and over, and adding them to your parent you should be wondering if an AdapterView i.e. ListView would be a better option. Almost always the answer is yes =)

Comment: So are you saying that I should replace the Relative Layout with listview or the parent (in my case a vertical Linear Layout)?  Also, will that allow me to give each of the items separate ids?

Comment: probably. If you use a ListView as your parent layout then you don't have to "manually" create each View, your adapter will do it for you based on your data objects. And you can set the onclicklisteners at the time the view is created so you don't need to know it's id.